# comparing ip and subnet (ipv4 and ipv6) - mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I check if an `ipaddress` is part of a `subnet`, given `ipaddress` can be ipv4 or ipv6?

I currently have it working for ipv4 only:

```
set @ip = '1.1.1.1';
set @subnet = '1.1.1.0/32';
set @xor_bw_ip_n_subnet = inet_aton(@ip) ^ inet_aton(substring_index(@subnet, '/', 1));
select ((@xor_bw_ip_n_subnet) >> 32-substring_index(@subnet,'/',-1)) = 0;   -- if ip in subnet, then should be 0
```

For ipv6, how can I use `inet6_ntoa/inet6_aton` to check if IPaddress is part of a subnet (basically trying to do bitwise operation on ipv6 address)?

I am using mysql v5.6.19

Thanks,

Comment: Recommend you do this processing in a programming language, not SQL.

Comment: It makes it really slow if I do it in a programming language, since... I have close to a million subnets to be searched within

Comment: Are you comparing 1 IP address to a million subnets?  Do your subnets overlap?

Comment: yes. I am comparing 1 ip address to a million subnets. the query perfectly works for ipv4 and is really quick. without this query, from python, its really slow. thats why i wish to do similarly for ipv6

Answer (score 1):

I assume your IPv6 is in `BINARY(16)`?  Build a 128-row table of the `BINARY(16)` values for the subnet masks.  (/128 is all 1's.)  `JOIN` to the table and do masking on each half of the address --

```
WHERE (LEFT(ip, 8)  & LEFT(mask, 8))  == LEFT(ip, 8)
  AND (RIGHT(ip, 8) & RIGHT(mask, 8)) == RIGHT(ip, 8)
```

(No shifting.)

Comment: yes, i am actually storing all the `ipaddresses` in a table with columns: `ipaddr` (as varbinary(16)), `ipprefixlength` (as integer). this table stores ipv4 and ipv6 both addresses which needs to be searched against a ipaddr

Comment: i am not that good at mysql, can you please provide an example?

Comment: sorry, but dont `LEFT` and `RIGHT` only work on string?

Comment: never mind, i solved it using javascript/node.js ip-addr programmatic approach... its decently fast